# Have I successfully installed TensorFlow and Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

On Jupyter Notebook, I have the following code:

```
!pip install keras
!pip install tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
```

Under it, it spits out this after I've ran it.

```
 Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from h5py->keras) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\nollb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
```

There's more lines but does this mean keras and tensorflow have been successfully installed and I can start using the packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also run the following code snippet in your jupyter notebook to check this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.version.VERSION

import keras
keras.__version__
```

However, As the output states:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow 
Requirement already satisfied: keras
```

Both packages have been installed, and you can start using them!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact it means that `tensorflow` and `keras` had already been installed ("Requirement already satisfied").

You can verify this by running

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3
```

Note that nowadays it is recommended to use `tensorflow.keras` which is integrated into tensorflow instead of the standalone `keras` package.

Comment: Ah ok. That's probably much more space efficient. Thank you for your help!